# Change default formatting of \author with Sciposter class

Tags: titles, fontsize, sciposter

Latex is something new to me, so I don't know some basics yet. I am making a poster with `sciposter` and want to change the formatting of the authors names. The names are written in bold by default, and I want them to come out as normal text. How can I do that?

So far, the only thing I was able to change in the author output was its size, with the `\renewcommand{\authorsize}{\Large}` command.

Comment: Welcome, add `\normalfont` fter `\Large`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class formats the author in the title using the following:

```
{\authorsize {\bf\@author} \par}
```

The above shows that the `\@author` - stored with a call to `\author{<author>}` is *always* set in [`\bf`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516/5764), making changes to `\authorsize` that include font weight completely useless. Perhaps that was the intent as the macros only refers to *size*, not the *font*. Redefining `\authorsize` to remove `\bf` is an option:

[image]

```
\documentclass{sciposter}

\leftlogo[0.52]{example-image-10x16}
\title{Generalized Pattern Spectra Sensitive to Spatial Information}
\author{Michael H.F. Wilkinson}
\institute{Institute for Mathematics and Computing Science \\
  University of Groningen, P.O. Box 800, 9700 AV Groningen,
  The Netherlands}
\email{michael@cs.rug.nl}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\authorsize}[1]{\mdseries\Large\@author}
\makeatother

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Patching `\maketitle` using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) is also an option:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\maketitle}% <cmd>
  {\authorsize {\bf\@author}}% <search>
  {{\bfseries\authorsize\@author}}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
```

The above patch reverses the use of `\bf` in setting the author, placing `\authorsize` *after* `\bfseries`. This allows you to introduce font weight and shape updates which should override the setting of the author in **bold** using something like

```
\renewcommand{\authorsize}{\mdseries\Large}
```

Comment: The patch may very well have done whatever you want to. The intent was to replicate the default **bold** behaviour, but still allow modifications via `\authorsize`.

Comment: I think redefine the command was exactly what I wanted. Thanks, thanks, thanks! :)